# How to best implement parent-child callbacks in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In the app I'm working on I have a form that includes an "item picker", which pushes on a new screen to select the item (via a stack navigator, which is the parent component to both screens).  All I really need is for the "child" (the item picker) to tell the "parent" (the form) which item was selected.

There seem to be a couple sensible ways to do this according to the react-navigation docs:

- Use a reducer.  I could set the selected item using `dispatch`, but this would move the "selected item" state all the way up to the "main" screen. Why?  Because the child screen is not a subview of the form screen, it is a child view of the *navigation*, which is one level above the form.  Ideally, as a good separation of concerns, the form would maintain its own state, and would only tell the main screen about the completed form/object.  So this isn't an ideal solution.
- Passing the item as a param "up" to the form.  In this scenario, the form has a `selectedItem: Item|undefined` property.  This also has a code smell to me; for one thing, the child screen would have to hard code the form screen (`navigation.navigate('FormScreen', { selectedItem: item })`).

My current solution is to assign a `onSelectItem` param to the item picker.  I like this solution because it makes the child screen generic; I could use it on any "parent" and all I have to do is hand it items and a callback. But this solution emits a warning about a non-serializable param.

Ideally I would use the state/reducer from the form screen, but I can't think of any way to make the reducer that I create in the parent available to the child, because both are actually children of the navigator.

Is there another solution that works here, or a way of using?

(btw I also considered using another nested stack navigation inside the form screen – in my case this would actually work because I'm not using the system navigation headers, but in general this doesn't feel right. Similarly, I could use a modal popup instead of pushing a view onto the stack, but this changes the UI drastically, which I don't want to do here.  Plus, as an exercise, I think there is probably a better solution out there).

As usual I'm not looking for "bike shedding" solutions – I want to know if there is a more elegant way for a screen further down the stack to send data UP the stack.

In iOS/Swift code I would create a delegate protocol and have the parent implement it, and have the child set the selected item via a method on its delegate, I'm looking for something similar to that pattern.

Comment: How about fragments and a react reducer with a context creator?

Comment: I don't follow - where would this fragment live, and what is inside it?